# In the screen or on the screen?

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know what is the correct version:

Let's say we have some IT system (like SAP) and there is a search screen. If I am asking someone to perform an action in the system, should I ask them to do something in the screen or on the screen?

Enter the information/data in the search screen. OR
Enter the information/date on the search screen?

Answer (score 2):

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22in+the+screen%22%2C%22on+the+screen%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) reports: *Ngrams not found: "in the screen"* and some minimal results for "on the screen".

In my experience (including years as a database administrator), data is entered **in (or into) a text-entry field**, which is displayed **on the screen**.